# When performing electrolysis of brine, are carbon steel electrodes ok?

Tags: electrolysis, carbon-allotropes

Are carbon steel electrodes better? Do they both eventually corrode? Is there any cheap electrode that stays inert indefinitely?

Comment: No Iron will oxidize before water and make a mess of iron oxides and carbon flakes as well a other metals in the iron.

Comment: Note that even Pt or Au anodes would be vulnerable to eventually forming $\ce{[PtCl6]^2-}$ or $\ce{[AuCl4]-}$. Possibly the best choice would be glassy carbon, but it is not (AFAIK) widely available for amateurs.

Comment: Steel electrodes for electrolysis, honestly? I think you missed a few crucial points in your textbook! Go back and read some more before the next experiment. :)

Answer (score 4):

Anode materials for electrolytic production of chlorine, a corrosive gas, are not that simple. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chloralkali_process) gives a good description of what works ... and what doesn't. The tl, dr is that in industry, titanium anodes clad with a mixture of conducting oxides such as $\ce{PtO2}$ and $\ce{IrO2}$ are used in this application (and others requiring a conductive yet chemically resistant material):

> Due to the corrosive nature of chlorine production, the anode (where the chlorine is formed) must be non-reactive and has been made from materials such as platinum metal,[1] graphite (called plumbago in Faraday's time),[1] or platinized titanium.[2] **A mixed metal oxide clad titanium anode (also called a dimensionally stable anode) is the industrial standard today.** Historically, platinum, magnetite, lead dioxide,[3] manganese dioxide, and ferrosilicon (13-15% silicon[4]) have also been used as anodes.[5] Platinum alloyed with iridium is more resistant to corrosion from chlorine than pure platinum.[5][6] Unclad titanium cannot be used as an anode because it anodizes, forming a non-conductive oxide and passivates. Graphite will slowly disintegrate due to internal electrolytic gas production from the porous nature of the material and carbon dioxide forming due to carbon oxidation, causing fine particles of graphite to be suspended in the electrolyte that can be removed by filtration. The cathode (where hydroxide forms) can be made from unalloyed titanium, graphite, or a more easily oxidized metal such as stainless steel or nickel. [Emphasis added.]

**Cited References**

1. Faraday, Michael (1849). Experimental Researches In Electricity. Vol. 1. London: The University of London.
2. Landolt, D.; Ibl, N. (1972). "Anodic chlorate formation on platinized titanium". *Journal of Applied Electrochemistry*. Chapman and Hall Ltd. 2 (3): 201–210. https://doi.irg/10.1007/BF02354977. S2CID 95515683.
3. Munichandraiah, N.; Sathyanarayana, S. (1988). "Insoluble anode of α-lead dioxide coated on titanium for electrosynthesis of sodium perchlorate". *Journal of Applied Electrochemistry*. Chapman and Hall Ltd. 18 (2): 314–316. doi:10.1007/BF01009281. S2CID 96759724.
4. Dinan, Charles (1927-10-15). "The Corrosion of Durion Anodes (BSc)." Massachusetts Institute of Technology. p. 4. hdl:1721.1/87815. Retrieved 2019-09-25.
5. Hale, Arthur (1918). *The Applications of Electrolysis in Chemical Industry*. Longmans, Green, and Co. p. 13. Retrieved 2019-09-15.
6. Denso, P. (1902). "Untersuchungen Über die Widerstandsfähigkeit von Platiniridium‐Anoden bei der Alkalichlorid‐Elektrolyse". *Zeitschrift für Elektrochemie. Wilhelm Knapp.* **8** (10): 149.